# Как сделать задержку срабатывания наведения :hover?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Есть меню, но при наведение на пункт надо сделать задержку срабатывания наведения
Как сделать задержку срабатывания стиля ?
Лучше через css? или лучше через java?

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_menu
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<ul class="<?php echo $class_sfx; ?>">
<?php 

$level_1 = []; $level_2 = []; $level_3 = []; $level_4 = [];

$mobmenu = [
    'level_1' => [],
    'level_2' => [],
    'level_3' => [],
    'level_4' => [],
    'level_5' => [],
];

foreach ($list as $i => &$item)
{
    if ($item->menutype === 'glavmenu2021') {
        if ($item->level == 1) array_push($level_1, $item);
        if ($item->level == 2) array_push($level_2, $item);
        if ($item->level == 3) array_push($level_3, $item);
        if ($item->level == 4) array_push($level_4, $item);

        continue;
    }

    if ($item->menutype === 'mobile2021') {
        if ($item->level == 1) array_push($mobmenu['level_1'], $item);
        if ($item->level == 2) array_push($mobmenu['level_2'], $item);
        if ($item->level == 3) array_push($mobmenu['level_3'], $item);
        if ($item->level == 4) array_push($mobmenu['level_4'], $item);
        if ($item->level == 5) array_push($mobmenu['level_5'], $item);

        continue;
    }

    $class = 'item-' . $item->id;

    if ($item->id == $default_id)
    {
        $class .= ' default';
    }

    if ($item->id == $active_id || ($item->type === 'alias' && $item->params->get('aliasoptions') == $active_id))
    {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type === 'alias')
    {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
        {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
        {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->type === 'separator')
    {
        $class .= ' divider';
    }

    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }

    if ($item->parent)
    {
        $class .= ' parent';
    }

    echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'component':
        case 'heading':
        case 'url':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower)
    {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?></ul>

<?php if ($item->menutype === 'mobile2021'): ?>
    <?php 

// print_r($mobmenu['level_1'][3]);

        echo '<ul class="mobmenu mobmenu_app">';
        foreach ($mobmenu['level_1'] as $key_l1 => $l1):
            $css = $l1->type !== 'url' ? 'mobmenu__opener' : '';
            
            echo '<li>
                    <div class="mobmenu__title '.$l1->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">
                        <a href="'.$l1->link.'" class="mobmenu__title-left '.$css.'">
                            <div class="mobmenu__title-img"><img src="'.$l1->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="mobmenu__title-txt">'.$l1->title.'</div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="mobmenu__title-right mobmenu__opener">
                            <div class="mobmenu__arrow arrow-bottom"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';

                    
                    $l2_first = 0;
                    foreach ($mobmenu['level_2'] as $key_l2 => $l2):
                        $css = $l2->type !== 'url' ? 'mobmenu__opener' : '';

                        if ($l2->parent_id == $l1->id) {
                            if ($l2_first === 0 ) echo '<ul class="mobmenu__submenu">';

                            echo '<li>
                                    <div class="mobmenu__title '.$l2->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">
                                        <a href="'.$l2->link.'" class="mobmenu__title-left '.$css.'">
                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-img"><img src="'.$l2->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></div>
                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-txt">'.$l2->title.'</div>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="mobmenu__title-right mobmenu__opener">
                                            <div class="mobmenu__arrow arrow-bottom"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>';


                                    $l3_first = 0;
                                    foreach ($mobmenu['level_3'] as $key_l3 => $l3):
                                        $css = $l3->type !== 'url' ? 'mobmenu__opener' : '';

                                        if ($l3->parent_id == $l2->id) {
                                            if ($l3_first === 0 ) echo '<ul class="mobmenu__submenu">';

                                            echo '<li>
                                                    <div class="mobmenu__title '.$l3->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">
                                                        <a href="'.$l3->link.'" class="mobmenu__title-left '.$css.'">
                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-img"><img src="'.$l3->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></div>
                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-txt">'.$l3->title.'</div>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <div class="mobmenu__title-right mobmenu__opener">
                                                            <div class="mobmenu__arrow arrow-bottom"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>';


                                                    $l4_first = 0;
                                                    foreach ($mobmenu['level_4'] as $key_l4 => $l4):
                                                        $css = $l4->type !== 'url' ? 'mobmenu__opener' : '';

                                                        if ($l4->parent_id == $l3->id) {
                                                            if ($l4_first === 0 ) echo '<ul class="mobmenu__submenu">';

                                                            echo '<li>
                                                                    <div class="mobmenu__title '.$l4->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">
                                                                        <a href="'.$l4->link.'" class="mobmenu__title-left '.$css.'">
                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-img"><img src="'.$l4->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></div>
                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-txt">'.$l4->title.'</div>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                        <div class="mobmenu__title-right mobmenu__opener">
                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__arrow arrow-bottom"></div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>';


                                                                    $l5_first = 0;
                                                                    foreach ($mobmenu['level_5'] as $key_l5 => $l5):
                                                                        $css = $l5->type !== 'url' ? 'mobmenu__opener' : '';

                                                                        if ($l5->parent_id == $l4->id) {
                                                                            if ($l5_first === 0 ) echo '<ul class="mobmenu__submenu">';
                
                                                                            echo '<li>
                                                                                    <div class="mobmenu__title '.$l5->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">
                                                                                        <a href="'.$l5->link.'" class="mobmenu__title-left '.$css.'">
                                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-img"><img src="'.$l5->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></div>
                                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__title-txt">'.$l5->title.'</div>
                                                                                        </a>
                                                                                        <div class="mobmenu__title-right mobmenu__opener">
                                                                                            <div class="mobmenu__arrow arrow-bottom"></div>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </li>';
                
                                                                            $l5_first++;
                                                                        }
                                                                    endforeach;
                                                                    if ($l5_first !== 0 ) echo '</ul>';


                                                            echo '</li>';

                                                            $l4_first++;
                                                        }
                                                    endforeach;
                                                    if ($l4_first !== 0 ) echo '</ul>';

                                                    
                                                echo '</li>';

                                            $l3_first++;
                                        }
                                    endforeach;
                                    if ($l3_first !== 0 ) echo '</ul>';


                            echo '</li>';

                            $l2_first++;
                        }
                    endforeach;
                    if ($l2_first !== 0 ) echo '</ul>';
                    


            echo '</li>';

        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';

        echo "<style>
        .mobmenu{padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase}.mobmenu *{box-shadow:none!important}.mobmenu li{list-style:none;cursor:pointer}.mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__submenu{max-height:2000px;transition:max-height .35s ease-in}.mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__title{background:#f0f0f0}.mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__title>.mobmenu__title-right{visibility:visible}.mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__title>.mobmenu__title-right>.mobmenu__arrow{transform:rotate(225deg)}.mobmenu__parent>.mobmenu__title>.mobmenu__title-right{visibility:visible}.mobmenu__submenu{transition:max-height .15s ease-out;max-height:0;overflow:hidden;margin-top:10px;padding:0;margin:0;padding-left:0!important;display:block!important}.mobmenu__title{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:space-between;padding:8px 15px;position:relative}.mobmenu__title.yellow{background:#ffdb4e!important}.mobmenu__title-left{display:flex;flex:1;color:#000;min-height:0!important}.mobmenu__title-right{width:50px;height:25px;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;visibility:hidden}.mobmenu__title-txt{padding:0 10px;line-height:25px}.mobmenu__title-img{max-width:25px;max-height:25px}.mobmenu__title-img img{width:100%}.mobmenu__arrow{transform:rotate(45deg);transition:all .3s}.mobmenu_app .mobmenu__arrow{transform:rotate(315deg)}.mobmenu_app .mobmenu__submenu{transition:none}.mobmenu_app .mobmenu__parent.open{position:absolute!important;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#fff;z-index:100;padding-top:45px}.mobmenu_app .mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__title{flex-direction:row-reverse}.mobmenu_app .mobmenu__parent.open>.mobmenu__title>.mobmenu__title-right>.mobmenu__arrow{transform:rotate(135deg)}.arrow-bottom{border-bottom:2px solid #0b458f;border-right:2px solid #0b458f;width:8px;height:8px}
            </style>

            <script>
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    (function() {
                        const mobmenu = document.querySelector('.mobmenu')
                        const liList = mobmenu.querySelectorAll('li')
                        const subList = mobmenu.querySelectorAll('.mobmenu__submenu')
                
                        liList.forEach((el) => {
                            if (el.querySelector('.mobmenu__submenu')) {
                                el.classList.add('mobmenu__parent')
                                el.querySelector('.mobmenu__title').classList.add('mobmenu__title_parent')
                            }
                        })
                
                        mobmenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                            if (!e.target.closest('.mobmenu__opener')) return;
                
                            e.preventDefault()
                
                            const eParent = e.target.closest('.mobmenu__parent')
                            const subMenu = eParent.querySelector('.mobmenu__submenu')
                            
                            eParent.classList.toggle('open')
                            closeOther(e.target)
                        })
                
                        function closeOther(target) {
                            const targetOpen = target.closest('.mobmenu__parent')
                
                            mobmenu.querySelectorAll('.mobmenu__parent').forEach((el) => {
                                const parent = [...el.querySelectorAll('.mobmenu__parent')]
                                
                                if (!parent.includes(targetOpen) && targetOpen !== el) {
                                    el.classList.remove('open')
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }());
                })
            </script>";
            
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ($item->menutype === 'glavmenu2021'): ?>
<div style="background: #218cc6; width: 100%;">
<div class="wrapper clr">
<div class="mymenu">
<?php 
    // $level_1 = []; $level_2 = []; $level_3 = []; $level_4 = [];
    
    // foreach ($list as $i => &$item) {
    //  if ($item->menutype === 'glavmenu2021') {
    //      if ($item->level == 1) array_push($level_1, $item);
    //      if ($item->level == 2) array_push($level_2, $item);
    //      if ($item->level == 3) array_push($level_3, $item);
    //      if ($item->level == 4) array_push($level_4, $item);
    //  }
    // }

    foreach ($level_1 as $key => $l1) {
        echo '<div class="mymenu__item">';
        $l1_id = $l1->id;
        
        echo '<a href="'.$l1->link.'" class="mymenu__item-link">'.$l1->title.'</a>';

        echo '<div class="mymenu__item-body"> <div class="mymenu__submenu">';
        $l2_ids = [];
        $active = 'active';
        foreach ($level_2 as $l2) {
            if ($l2->parent_id == $l1_id) {
                echo '<a href="'.$l2->link.'" class="mymenu__submenu-link tabs '. $active .'" data-target="'.$l2->id.'">'.$l2->title.'</a>';

                $l2_ids['id'][] = $l2->id;
                $l2_ids['css_type'][] = $l2->params['menu-anchor_css'];

                $active = '';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';

        $active = 'active';
        foreach ($l2_ids['id'] as $key_l2 => $l2_id) {
            echo '<div class="mymenu__content mymenu__content_'.$l2_ids['css_type'][$key_l2].' '. $active .'" id="'.$l2_id.'">';
            $active = '';


            $level_3_filtred = [];
            foreach ($level_3 as $item) {
                if ($item->parent_id === $l2_id) {
                    array_push($level_3_filtred, $item);
                }
            }
            $count_in_column = $l2_ids['css_type'][$key_l2] === 'column' ? ceil(count($level_3_filtred) / 5) : 1;
            // echo '<pre>';
            // print_r($count_in_column);
            // echo '</pre>';

            for ($q = 0; $q < 5; $q++) {

                $l3_arr = [];
                for ($c = 0; $c < $count_in_column; $c++) {
                    $indx = $q + ($c * 5);
                    array_push($l3_arr, $level_3_filtred[$indx]);
                }

                echo '<div class="content">';
                
                foreach ($l3_arr as $key_l3 => $l3) {
                    if (!$l3) break;
                    echo $key_l3 > 0 ? '<br>' : false;
                    if ($l3->type === 'url') {

                        if ($l3->params['menu_image']) {
                            echo '<a href="'.$l3->link.'"><img src="/'.$l3->params['menu_image'].'" alt=""></a>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<div class="content__h"><a href="'.$l3->link.'">'.$l3->title.'</a></div>';
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="content__h">'.$l3->title.'</div>';
                    }
                    
                    $l3_id = $l3->id;
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($level_4 as $l4) {
                        if ($l4->parent_id == $l3_id) {
                            if ($i % 11 === 0 && $i !== 0 && $l2_ids['css_type'][$key_l2] === 'column') {
                                echo '</div><div class="content"><div class="content__h">&nbsp;</div>';
                            }
                            $i++;
    
                            if ($l4->type === 'url') {
                                echo '<a href="'.$l4->link.'" class="content__a '.$l4->params['menu-anchor_css'].'">'.$l4->title.'</a>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<div class="content__h" style="margin-top:15px">'.$l4->title.'</div>';
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo '</div>';
            }

            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div> </div>';


        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($l4->type);
        // echo '</pre>';


        if (count($level_1) === $key + 1) {
            echo '
            
            <style>
            .mymenu{
            background:#218cc6;
            display:flex;
            position:relative;
        
                
            }
            .mymenu__item-body{
            display:none;
            background:#fff;
            position:absolute;
            top:100%;
            left:-10px;
            right:0;
            padding:15px 0;
            z-index:1000
                
            }
            .mymenu__item-link{
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:7px 10px;
            display:block;
            color:#fff


                
            }
            .mymenu__item-link:hover{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fff
                
            }
            .mymenu__item:not(:last-of-type){
            margin-right:15px
            
                
            }
            .mymenu__item:hover{
            background:#1e80b4
              
            }
            
    
        .mymenu__item-body{
        display:none;
        
            
             }
        
            .mymenu__item:hover .mymenu__item-body{
            display:flex;
    
                
            }
            .mymenu__submenu{
            margin-right:30px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column
                
            }
            .mymenu__submenu-link{
            font-weight:bold;
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:10px 20px;
            background:#f2f3f5;
            border-right:#f2f3f5 solid 2px;
            color: #0b458fcf;
            min-width:230px;
            border-radius:0 10px 0 0
                
            }
            .mymenu__submenu-link:not(:last-of-type){
            margin-bottom:10px
                
            }
            .mymenu__submenu-link:hover{
            color:#218cc6!important;
            text-decoration:none
                
            }
            .mymenu__submenu-link.active,.mymenu__submenu-link:hover{
            border-right:#218cc6 solid 2px
                
            }
            .mymenu__content{
            display:none
            
        

                
            }
            .mymenu__content a:hover{
            color:#218cc6!important
                
            }
            .mymenu__content.active{
            display:flex
            

                
            }
            .mymenu__content .content:not(:last-of-type){
            margin-right:30px
                
            }
            .mymenu__content .content__h{
            font-weight:700;
            margin-bottom:10px
                
            }
            .mymenu__content .content__a{
            color:#808d9a;
            margin-bottom:10px
                
            }
            .mymenu__content .content__a{
            display:inline-block
                
            }
            .mymenu__content .content__a.red{
            color:red
                
            }
            
            .mymenu__content .content__a.blue{
            color:#4169e1
                
            }.mymenu__content .content__h a{color:#274897;text-decoration:underline}.mymenu__content .row{margin-bottom:20px}.mymenu__content .row__h{font-weight:700;margin-bottom:10px}.mymenu__content .row .content__a{margin-right:10px}.mymenu__content_img{flex-wrap:wrap}.mymenu__content_img .content{max-width:calc(100% / 4 - 15px);margin-right:15px!important;margin-bottom:15px}.mymenu__content_img img{width:100%}.mymenu__content_column{flex-wrap:wrap;width:100%}.mymenu__content_column .content{display:flex;flex-direction:column;margin-bottom:25px;width:calc(20% - 30px)}.mymenu__content_row{flex-direction:column}.mymenu__content_row .content{margin-bottom:20px}.mymenu__content_row .content__a{margin-right:10px}
                </style>';

            echo " <script>
                    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    console.log('ok')
                    

                    const mymenu = document.querySelector('.mymenu')
                    
                    $('.mymenu').on('mouseover', (e) => {
                        if (e.target.classList.contains('tabs')) {
                            const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-target')

                            const mymenu__item = e.target.closest('.mymenu__item')
                            const mymenu__content = $(mymenu__item).find('.mymenu__content')
                            const mymenu__submenuLink = $(mymenu__item).find('.mymenu__submenu-link')

                            mymenu__submenuLink.each(function (i) {
                                const el = $( this )[0]
                                
                                if (el === e.target) {
                                    el.classList.add('active')
                                } else {
                                    el.classList.remove('active')
                                }
                            })
                            
                            mymenu__content.each(function () {
                                const el = $( this )[0]
                                
                                if (el.getAttribute('id') === id) {
                                    el.classList.add('active')
                                } else {
                                    el.classList.remove('active')
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                });
                </script>";
        }
    }
    

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element:hover {
  animation-name: your-name;
  animation-delay: 1000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes your-name {
  100% {
    /* Ваши стили */
    background: #1e80b4;

  }
}
```